# Updated Table Names, Update Views with new table names

Tags: sql, sql-server

I recently renamed all of my tables within the SQL Server database and now the views (about 20 and growing) do not work because they point to the wrong table names. Is there a way to update them all at the same time so I do not have to go one by one into each view and do a find and replace?

Answer (score 0):

1- Generate a drop script for these views(using Management Studio or a tool like redgate)

2- Generate the create script of all these views (using Management Studio or a tool like redgate)

3- Open the create script on an editor and replace all the changed table names

4- run the create script

5- run the drop script